# Programmatically LinearLayout Weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to develop similar to grid but using `LinearLayout`. I would like to have 3 images and exact bottom text after images in single row.

[image]

What I have tried:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
Item item = getItem(page, index);
Log.e("tag", item.getDrawable());
imageLoader.displayImage(item.getDrawable(), icon, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
icon.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

layout.addView(icon);

TextView label = new TextView(context);
label.setTag("text");
label.setText(item.getName());
label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
label.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.setWeightSum(3f);
layout.addView(label);
```

I've a view method which returns `View`so I return `return layout;` at the end of the method.
Here I 've given weight 3 button this is not working for me. And code show more then 3 images in row with text but would like to have weight 3 images and bottom text .

Comment: Weights can be specified as the third parameter in the `LayoutParams` constructor, for example: `layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`. The `f` stands for `float`, so in this case it would be a weight of `1`. You'll have to play around with this to get the desired effect.

Comment: Yes , I already have tried   layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f)); but this is not working for me .

Comment: `this is not working for me` is a very broad concept. Explain *why* it doesn't work, what you want to achieve and which result are you getting.

Comment: Sorry for the convenience, I would like to achieve similar view as I have posted in image : Row with image and textview bottom of ImageView so it should be similar to the GridView , Row with 3 images atleast that why i am using weight . Here even after giving weight it seems like it doesn't get effected of 1f or 3f , No doubt I admit I am doing something wrong , Trying hard to achieve it. Question is posted after googling . Thanks

Comment: I would define a `TableLayout` with as many `TableRow`s as you need. On each of those `TableRow`s, I'd add a `LinearLayout` with `VERTICAL` orientation consisting of the two `View`s you need: `ImageView` and `TextView`. This is the `LinearLayout` where you should set a weight of `1` (to all of them). You will have to get the screen's width and see whether the new `LinearLayout` to be added still fits the current row. If not, simply start a new `TableRow`.

Comment: @nKn Would be great if you can post this as answer so I can accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a `TableLayout` with as many `TableRow`s as you need. On each of those `TableRows`, I'd add a `LinearLayout` with `VERTICAL` orientation consisting of the two `View`s you need: `ImageView` and `TextView`.

This is the `LinearLayout` where you should set a weight of `1` (to all of them). You will have to get the screen's width and see whether the new `LinearLayout` to be added still fits the current row. If not, simply start a new `TableRow`.

To get the width of the screen you can use this:

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
```

The screen's width might be accessed via the `params.width` attribute, just compare it with your `LinearLayout`'s `.getWidth()` method and keep an incremental account (a `float`) of the current `TableRow`'s width to help you determine if the current item should be placed in an existing row or a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```

or

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have googled but these two are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Programmtically setting Linear Layout weight 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);